# How to use date for a new column name

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a new column to my `MYSQLi` table using `PHP`. I am unsure how to alter my table. I want to use data from Time to add new column like this

`Time               |  2016-Mar-06-22:40
  2016-Mar-06-22:40 |          YES`

Edit : And when the time has change, a new column will create  like this

`Time              |  2016-Mar-06-22:40  |  2016-Mar-06-23:00 
  2016-Mar-06-23:00|          YES        |         NO`

This is my code

```
 $MyTime = date("Y-M-d-H:i"); 
 $sql = $conn->query("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD $MyTime enum('YES', 'NO') ");
```

I tried to add `2016-Mar-06-22:40` in `phpMyAdmin` and it's done, but when I try to make it in `php` `mysqli` code, it didn't create new column for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is simple: you should **never ever** add any column that looks like a datetime. Such values have to be stored as *data values*, not column names.

What you probably want is a *related* table to store datetime values.

The database you are using is called *relational* for a reason. Means you don't have to store all the required data in the same table. Instead ,you can use several tables while installing *relations* between them.

So, you probably need a table like this

```
main_table_id | datetime          | value
```

and then insert into this table any number or records like

```
1             | 2016-Mar-06-22:40 | YES
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I want to add multiple datetime with values (Yes/No) for each data. What should I do.

Comment: You really should heed this advice; but if you absolutely have to ignore it, then a column name that contains characters like `:` must be enclosed in backticks (`\``)

Comment: Thankyou Mark Baker. I've got my answer from yours. ^^